# Node.JS: How to scrape a json page for specific data

Tags: json, node.js, web-scraping, module

I would like to scrape this page: [calendar events](http://umd.bwcs-hosting.com/feeder/main/eventsFeed.do?f=y&sort=dtstart.utc:asc&fexpr=(categories.href!=%22/public/.bedework/categories/sys/Ongoing%22%20and%20categories.href!=%22/public/.bedework/categories/Campus%20Bulletin%20Board%22)%20and%20(entity_type=%22event%22%7Centity_type=%22todo%22)&skinName=list-json&count=30)

for specific data, like formattedDate and description. How do I go about that in a module in Node.JS. I am having a hard time understanding the process in Node.JS.

Any help would go a long way, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3):

it's pretty simple, you can import the request module and use it. For example, see code below.

```
const request = require("request");

request("MY_URL", (error, response, body) => {
  console.log('body:', body);
});
```

Also, you can try this here, on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IrritatingRundownTranslation)

First of all, you need to parse your JSON, this allows you to access fields from received json.

```
const data = JSON.parse(body);
```

Now, if you want to access some information about an event you need to loop events and access what you need, something like:

```
const events = data.bwEventList.events;
events.map((data, index) => console.log(data.calendar))
```

Final code also on [Repl.it](https://repl.it/repls/IrritatingRundownTranslation)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Would you be able to show me a possible loop example. I having difficulty creating a working one.

Comment: .map does that, look here 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Answer (score 0):

from nodeJS docs [here](https://nodejs.org/api/http.html#http_http_get_options_callback)

```
    const http = require('http');

    http.get('http://umd.bwcs-hosting.com/feeder/main/eventsFeed.do?f=y&sort=dtstart.utc:asc&fexpr=(categories.href!=%22/public/.bedework/categories/sys/Ongoing%22%20and%20categories.href!=%22/public/.bedework/categories/Campus%20Bulletin%20Board%22)%20and%20(entity_type=%22event%22%7Centity_type=%22todo%22)&skinName=list-json&count=30', (res) => {
      const { statusCode } = res;
      const contentType = res.headers['content-type'];

      let error;
      if (statusCode !== 200) {
        error = new Error('Request Failed.\n' +
                          `Status Code: ${statusCode}`);
      } 
      if (error) {
        console.error(error.message);
        // consume response data to free up memory
        res.resume();
        return;
      }

      res.setEncoding('utf8');
      let rawData = '';
      res.on('data', (chunk) => { rawData += chunk; });
      res.on('end', () => {
        try {
          const parsedData = JSON.parse(rawData);
          console.log(parsedData["bwEventList"]["resultSize"]);
        } catch (e) {
          console.error(e.message);
        }
      });
    }).on('error', (e) => {
      console.error(`Got error: ${e.message}`);
    });
```

see `console.log(parsedData["bwEventList"]["resultSize"]);`
slice parsedData as an array until you get what you want